# Angular ngrx reducer

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I am recently learning Angular with @ngrx/store while one of the tutorial is to use @ngrx/store for state management,
I'm trying to use ngrx to add data in a table ( table from angular material ) using input but I have an error that I don't understand, I'm quite junior and I don't know ngrx at all.

here is my error : **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')** the error comes from the reducer

**ts.file**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private ELEMENT_DATA!: PeriodicElement[];
  public displayedColumns: string[] = ['name'];
  public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>(
    this.ELEMENT_DATA
  );

  public tableName!: Observable<PeriodicElement[]>;

  constructor(
    private tableService: TableService,
    private store: Store<reducer.State>
  ) {
    this.tableName = store.select(tableSelector.selectAll);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.select(tableSelector.selectAll).subscribe((res) => {});
    this.get();
  }

  get() {
    this.tableService
      .getTableDetails()
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.dataSource.data = data;
      });
  }

  add(name: any) {
    this.store.dispatch({ type: action.Add });
    // this.tableService.create(name).subscribe((data: string) => {
    //     this.get();
    //   });
  }
```

**action.ts**

```
export const Add = '[PeriodicElement] Add';
export const addTable = createAction(
  Add, props<{payload:PeriodicElement}>()
)

export class AddPeriodicElement implements Action {
  readonly type = Add;
  constructor(public payload: PeriodicElement) {}
}

export type Actions = AddPeriodicElement;
```

**reducer.ts**

```
export const tableAdapter: EntityAdapter<PeriodicElement> =
  createEntityAdapter<PeriodicElement>({});
export interface State extends EntityState<PeriodicElement> {}
export const initialeState: State = tableAdapter.getInitialState();

const tableReducer = createReducer(
  initialeState,
  on(TableActions.addTable, (state, { payload}) => {
    console.log('state', state);
    console.log('payload', payload);
    return tableAdapter.addOne(payload, state);
  })
);

export function reducer(state: State | undefined, action: Action) {
  return tableReducer(state, action);
}
```

**selector.ts**

```
export const getTable = createFeatureSelector<tableReducer.State>('toto');

export const { selectAll } = tableReducer.tableAdapter.getSelectors(getTable);
```

**interface**

```
export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
}
```